# Wordpress: adding a custom menu class through "nav_menu_css_class" doesnt' work

Tags: wordpress, class, menu, customization

I'm trying to add a custom menu class to each item and the attempt is to use the official solution suggested by the wordpress codex page.

This is function I added to function.php :

```
function special_nav_class($classes, $item){
 $classes[] = "new-class";
 return $classes;
}
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'special_nav_class' , 10 , 2);
```

The function doesn't work since I can't see any "new-class" in the source file of the website (using firebug).
Plus I can't understand if the hook call fill up the $classes and $item parameters.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The code you've provided above works perfectly. It adds the class `new-class` to the `<li>` element that encloses each `<a>` tag.

Comment: It should since it comes from the official wordpress codex but it doesn't work in my website. What could be the issues?